# County-level data fixed effect

Tags: fixed-effects-model

I am using county-level data in my dissertation, and I received the below comment regarding analysis from my supervisor;
"you mention that you use county-year FE. Since the outcome variable is also at the county-year level, it is unclear how the regression coefficients are estimated (they should be all dropped). In the tables, you specify county FE and year FE separately, which is why the regression coefficient is successfully estimated."

I wondered if it is not possible to use country-year fixed together for county-level data. Do I need to show the county and year effect separately?

Comment: It sounds like he's asking you to simply clarify your statement wrt 'county-year FEs'. He notes that in the tables, you state that these are two separate effects, whereas your statement of 'county-year FEs' combines them into an interaction or two-way FE. The statement in the tables is correct. Use that throughout the rest of your dissertation.

Comment: Thank you very much, Mike Hunter.